# Laravel file store returns tmp file name

Tags: php, laravel-5, storage

simple question. I tried to save a file to storage from a form post. Code:

```php
$path = $request->file('image')->store('image');
```

But the `$path` returns as `/tmp/phpCCTWsV`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form, all files will save into tmp folder. Then you must save them to storage. Ex:

```
$disk = Storage::disk('local');
$path = '/app/public/images/';
$name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$disk->put(str_replace('/app', '', $path) . $name, $request->file('image'));
$path .= $name; // This file's saved in `/storage/app/app/public/images/` folder
```